# Can an identifier attribute be multivalued in an E-R Diagram?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I am drawing an E-R diagram for one of my courses. The problem is I need to draw an ER diagram for a STUDENT and their respective REPORT CARD.

STUDENT has the attributes Name, Campus Address, Major and ID. REPORT CARD has the attributes Title, Instructor Name, Instructor Location, Grade, and Course ID.

I need to create an identifier attribute as per the instructions. I was thinking of using Course ID as the identifier attribute.

Obviously a student can be enrolled in more than one course. So could Course ID serve as an identifier attribute ({Course ID})?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Instructions:

> The figure below shows a grade report that is mailed to students at the end of each semester. Develop an E-R diagram reflecting the data contained in the grade report. Assume that each course is taught by one instructor. You need to make your own (reasonable) assumptions regarding the relationship cardinality if it is not explicitly indicated. Show your assumptions in your solution. You need to indicate which attribute you choose for the identifier of each entity type. You may create an identifier attribute if needed.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPXuJ.png

Comment: "I need to create an identifier attribute as per the instructions." What instructions? An identifier for what? What is a report card reporting on? You talk about "their" report card. Did they write it? Receive it? How do you know? Do you want to record something about that? Also: What do you think Course IDs identify?  Also: I have a bunch of report cards. What do you tell me to get a particular one? PS Why do you say students & report cards have those particular attributes? What is your actual *assignment* text? Please be more clear. In particular when referring to things.

Comment: What does this have to do with "multivalued"?

Comment: @philipxy Thanks for the response, I have edited my original post with the instructions.

Comment: Please answer/address all the questions in my comments. They aren't expressing bafflement, they are trying to help you learn. (Or I would be a lot more direct.) Eg: Quoting those instructions has not clarified your language. A report card could have been about the teacher's performance. That was actually more likely given what you say are the atttributes of a report card. Eg your language doesn't distinguish between what you were given & your design. (Give pseudo-DDL.) So please, those comments. And, what is your question? PS [Re images/links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3404097).

Comment: Your title asks question, but even after reading your post it's not clear what it means. (I suspect you are talking about composite keys, not multivalued attributes.) (Also, there's no such thing as a multivalued attribute of a relation.) Your post says "the problem is", "I need" & "I was thinking of", which you might think asks a question, but it's not clear what it would be if it were, which it isn't. Asking for "any help" is too broad & vague. Help with what, exactly? Maybe your question is "could Course ID serve as an identifier attribute". Of what? What does "serve as" mean, exactly?

Comment: @philipxy Sorry for the confusing question, I will try and clarify. I am struggling to find a way to create an identifier attribute between the entity STUDENT and REPORT CARD. I thought of using Course ID as the identifier, but I realized that STUDENTS can have multiple Course IDs, which led me to the initial question. Could I create an associative entity COURSE ID between STUDENT and REPORT CARD?

Comment: I keep saying, answer my questions. Start with "I have a bunch of report cards. What do you tell me to get a particular one?" PS I am not suffering from your post but the more info you put in it & show you are thinking the less I have to say "probably you are thinking..." & "probably the spec says..." etc etc. Essentially, if you are not clear then you haven't asked a question yet.

Comment: @philipxy If I am understanding your question properly, I would ask you about the Course ID in order to get the information about the course. Let me know if I misinterpreted your question.

Comment: That's not *enough*. Plus you might be able to get one by asking about *other* things. Why not *ask* me for one *right now*?

Comment: @philipxy I would be asking for the Grade, using the Course ID, Title, Instructor Name, and Instructor Location?

Comment: I find it odd you can't just say, please give the report card for grade 7, course CS101, Intro to CS, Professor Ponzo, room 222. By the way, Intro to CS is likely redundant given Course ID, and you still haven't told me enough to return a report card, so you haven't identified enough attributes/properties (everyday sense) to identify one. (And whether Title "is" an attribute/property of a report card needs to be formalized.)

Comment: @philipxy That was what I was trying to explain before, I would those attributes in an associative entity to get the grade. I am not sure what else I could possibly ask to receive the grade, those are all the attributes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153993/discussion-between-philipxy-and-rmahesh).